# Batch File Get Last Modified Date whille looping thru subdirectories

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, last-modified

I am looping through all subdirectories inside a directory, and wish to both save and echo the last modified date of each.

I cannot figure out the right type of `for` loop to do this. The following works to get me the subdirectory names, but I am unable to get their last modified date.

```bash
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a:d /o:n !some_path')...
```

I have to do an extra `forfiles` loop to get the last modified date of each subdirectory, which is very slow.

Is there a faster way to combine both looping over each subdirectory and get the last modified date for each, while also getting their full path?

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP and MySQL, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: Because the end result will be used in mysql and to replace php ciode.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If this problem is **really** related to PHP and MySQL, share the corresponding code

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /ad "*" ') DO ECHO %%~fb^|%%~tb
```

where the caret escapes the pipe to reproduce the pipe as an ordinary character (column separator)